# How to replace only part of a numpy array's values with those of another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to do something along the lines of a masked broadcast, where only certain values are broadcasted.

Suppose I have one bigger array, bigger_array, and one smaller array, smaller_array:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

bigger_array = np.zeros((4,4), dtype=np.int32)
smaller_array = np.ones((2,2), dtype=np.int32)
```

Now, I only want the first three values of the smaller array to replace those of a certain section of the bigger array, but masking doesn't do what I'd hoped it would do:

```
masked_smaller_array = ma.masked_array(smaller_array, mask=[(0, 0), (0, 1)])
bigger_array[2:4, 2:4] = masked_smaller_array
```

This just returns the same thing a regular broadcast would, namely:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1]]
```

Instead of my hoped for

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0]]
```

Stripping out the masked value before overriding via

```
bigger_array[2:4, 2:4] = masked_smaller_array[~masked_smaller_array.mask]
```

is also of no use as that flattens the array making broadcasting incompatible.

Is there some other way to achieve the same effect perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close when you had -

```
bigger_array[2:4, 2:4] = masked_smaller_array[~masked_smaller_array.mask]
```

You were just needed to index the left side of the equation to use the same mask over there as well. Thus, one way to solve it would be to fix it, like so -

```
# Mask corresponding to smaller array from where elements are to be taken
select_mask = ~masked_smaller_array.mask

# Use the mask on source (smaller array) to select specific elements from it 
# and update sliced and masked (with same mask) places in bigger array
bigger_array[2:4, 2:4][select_mask] = smaller_array[select_mask]
```

Sample run -

```
In [59]: bigger_array = np.zeros((4,4), dtype=np.int32)
    ...: smaller_array = np.ones((2,2), dtype=np.int32)
    ...: masked_smaller_array =ma.masked_array(smaller_array,mask=[(0, 0),(0, 1)])
    ...: 

In [60]: select_mask = ~masked_smaller_array.mask

In [61]: select_mask
Out[61]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True, False]], dtype=bool)

In [62]: bigger_array[2:4, 2:4][select_mask] = smaller_array[select_mask]

In [63]: bigger_array
Out[63]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually could use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with your mask as condition and fill it with `smaller_array` when condition is true. Btw IIUC you could use `make_mask` instead of `masked_array` for that purpose:

```
your_mask = [(0, 0), (0, 1)]
mask = ma.make_mask(your_mask)
np.where(~mask, smaller_array, bigger_array[2:4, 2:4])


In [106]: mask
Out[106]: 
array([[False, False],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [108]: np.where(~mask, smaller_array, bigger_array[2:4, 2:4])
Out[108]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Then you could assign that for your variable